# Django: Adding more fields to each ManyToMany Field option

Tags: python, django

Is It possible to add one or more Char Fields to each ManyToMany field option?

[image]

My Models:

```
class engineeringUni(models.Model):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    des_eng = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='Add description')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.field2

    def description_eng_universities(self):
        return self.des_eng

class engineering_courses(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    course_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='This is a description')
    course_offered_by = models.ManyToManyField(engineeringUni, related_name='course_offered_by')
    course_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default='2')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

    def description_course(self):
        return self.course_description

    def offered_by_courses(self):
        return self.course_offered_by

    def duration_courses(self):
        return str(self.course_duration)
```

As you can see in the image, I have the options in the ManyToMany field. Those options are:

- University 1
- University 2
- University 3

What I want to have is an additional text (Char) field next to each of these options (University 1, University 2, University 3).

Is this possible?

**EDIT 1:**

Current code:

```
class engineering_courses(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    course_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='This is a description')
    course_offered_by = models.ManyToManyField(
        engineeringUni, 
        through='ThroughModel', 
        through_fields=('course', 'university'),
        )
    course_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default='2')



    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

    def description_course(self):
        return self.course_description

    def offered_by_courses(self):
        return self.course_offered_by

    def duration_courses(self):
        return str(self.course_duration)



class ThroughModel(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(engineering_courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    university = models.ForeignKey(engineeringUni, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    additional_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**EDIT 2:** Problem fixed. I was getting that no table error because I had deleted the migration files and on deleting database (db.sqlite3) file and applying migration again, It fixed.

Comment: That might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships. That solves backend side of this problem. I'm not sure if there's a readymade solution in terms of form widget for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `through` model in the ManyToManyField ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)). This model can be used to store any additional fields.

```
class engineering_courses(models.Model):
    # ...
    course_offered_by = models.ManyToManyField(engineeringUni, related_name='course_offered_by', through='ThroughModel')


class ThroughModel(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(engineering_courses)
    university = models.ForeignKey(engineeringUni)
    additional_text = models.CharField()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I wasn't aware of Through models. 

So, I tried your code but now the ManyToMany Field is no more available in that engineering_courses. (In admin panel).

If I add that "ThroughModel" in admin.py `admin.site.register(ThroughModel)` then on opening ThroughModel in Admin page, It says



`OperationalError at /admin/theproject/throughmodel/

no such table: theproject_throughmodel`

Comment: I think you're missing the right makemigrations. Try running makemigrations and then migrate

Comment: I did that too but It didn't work. Even tried by resetting migrations (by removing migration files) but still same.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this Through model :)

Answer (score 3):

Take another look at the django docs referenced in the answer from arjun27. You have more than one foreign key in your ThroughModel, so django is confused. Try specifying the through fields in your engineering_course model, migrate the changes, and see if that works.

Mark

Comment: I missed those 'through_fields' again. Thanks to you for reminding me. Although I tried those It's still giving that error. One thing which I should specify is that If I directly click on "Add" next to "Through Models" instead of going to Through Models page, It does take me to page to add stuff (but saving displays the same error). I've edited my question and included my present code too, have a look on it too :) ~ Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for showing those "through fields" :)
Unfortunately, I don't have enough reps to upvote.